# Android/php: Populate AutoCompleteTextView list with rows of JSONArray from MySqli database table

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, mysqli

I'm trying to implement a database search function within my app, that searches a user table and returns an array of users that are *like* the search string. I need this array to populate the list that drops down below the acTextView, but I can't get the JSONArray to pass properly, and I'm not sure how I'd pass the data to the acTextView. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

App-side searching activity:

```
public class PopupAddContact extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup_add_contact);

    getWindow().setLayout(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    final AutoCompleteTextView searchInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchText);

    searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            final String name = searchInput.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        //ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);

                        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
                        System.out.println("working");


                        /*
                        if (jsonResponse != null) {

                            Integer contact_user_id = jsonResponse.getInt();
                            String contact_name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            String contact_email = jsonResponse.getString("email");



                        } else if(response != null){
                            Toast.makeText(PopupAddContact.this, "No users found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } */

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            PopupContactRequest AddContactRequest = new PopupContactRequest(name, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PopupAddContact.this);
            queue.add(AddContactRequest);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
```

PHP script to retreive an array of users:

```
if(!empty($_POST["name"])){ // check post data and then start
$mysqli = new mysqli("db creds"); 

$name = $_POST["name"];
$response=array(); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT user_id, name, email FROM users WHERE name LIKE %?%"; 

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) { // prepare query

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name); // bind parameters

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($data);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $response[] = $data; //assign each data to response array
    }

}

echo json_encode($response);

$mysqli->close();

}else{
    echo "no users found";
}
```

Comment: Could you add a json response? Just one response sample with results from the query

Comment: There's already a json_encoded echo near the end of the php script, or do you mean something different?

Comment: I mean the result of a call to the php page, as string. Or the string that you receive as a parameter in the onResponse(String response) method. One example with results as if there are no results you don't get a json in this case so it is going to create a JSONException when it is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your php file is not echoing a valid json, try changing this lines:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) { // prepare query

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name); // bind parameters

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $name, $email);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $response[] = [
            "user_id" => $user_id,
            "name" => $name,
            "email" => $email,
        ]; //assign each data to response array
    }
}

echo json_encode(array_values($response));
```

first you should call the php website and validate the result in a json validator like https://jsonlint.com/ and then you can continue with the java code.

It's also a good practice to write the json header before echoing the json response:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: It's still returning a blank array [ ]. I'm not sure where this is going wrong since it's definitely passing through the code to the point where it echoes the array, and if there are no users found it returns the `else` string.

Comment: Well,the 'No users found' is printed only if the $mysqli->prepare fails. And the query is not executed yet. So maybe that's the reason why you are getting the blank array. You should either move this text if you really need it if there is no result or change this error message. I would choose the second choice.

Comment: Oh right I overlooked that, it shouldn't really echo anything since it's just checking to make sure the search string contains something. It returns that echo properly if I clear the search bar, although I should change the string to "empty text" or something. I've still had no luck retrieving the array properly.